# Generated Github Page does not take me to the Actual Project (MAC)

Tags: github, github-pages

This is a dumb question, I know, but for some reason, my Rails project is not deploying on gh-pages.

Here's what I've tried.

1. I went into Settings, and clicked the Automatic Page Generator.
2. I click into my project and it takes me to a page that says

   Welcome to GitHub Pages.

   This automatic page generator is the easiest way to create beautiful pages for all of your projects.

not the actual webpage. Ok. I'll follow the directions and make a gh-pages branch and check it out.

1. I push the branch. It pushed but nothing happened.
2. I attempt to merge and receive an error.

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 1):

GitHub Pages can't be used to deploy a Ruby on Rails project. It can be used to create a static website, however. Push a commit to the `gh-pages` branch, and you'll see an update. Any errors will be sent to your email. If you're having trouble, contact support@github.com!

Comment: You can also use [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/) to generate static websites on GitHub Pages.